# Log4jConfigurer path

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j

I have an maven compatible eclipse dynamic project.I created eclipse dynamic project and turned it into maven project
When I put log4j.properties file under /src/main/resources/ it searches under /src/main/webapp directory adding the path I configure.
I can only make it work when I define

F:/path/to/config

as if I configure out of war.

What am I missing? Is there an example

thnx

Answer (score 0):

The log4j, by default, looks for the `log4j.properties` file in the classpath, so you don't need to use the class `PropertyConfigurator`, only if the file doesn't exist in the root of the classpath.

In the [Spring MVC + Log4j Integration Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/), you will see:

[image: location]

Comment: I don't use spring mvc.I am trying to find the cause of the problem.It does not work.Log files simply say the path is wrong.